# Efficient multiplication of (low-rank-block)-diagonal with vector in Pytorch (GPU)

Tags: performance, pytorch, gpu, linear-algebra

I have vectors `v` and `w` of length `n`, and an integer vector `x` of length `n` with `k` distinct values `i_0` through `i_{k-1}`. (For example, `x = [0,0,3,6,6,0,5,3,3]`).

What I want is the vector `y` where

```
y[x == i_j] = (v[x == i_j] @ w[x == i_j]) * w[x == i_j]
```

In some instances `k` will be very small, and in some it will be almost as big as `n`.

I want to do this fast on a GPU using Pytorch, but I know that doing a mask `v[x == i_j]` is slow, especially when done k times in a loop.

Maybe it would help at the beginning to apply the same permutation to `v`, `w`, and `x` so that `x` is sorted; then the pieces of `v` and `w` in question would be slices. And the permutation could be undone at the end.

In the sorted version, this amounts to multiplying the vector `v` by a block diagonal matrix, where each of the blocks in the block diagonal is a rank one matrix--the outer product of a slice of `w`. But I still don't know how to do this in O(n) time without just writing a loop (which would remove the GPU speedup). What pytorch functions should I use?

Comment: what are the dimensions of the vector product `v[..] @ w[..]`? what is the dimension of the output? are you mixing metric product `@` with element-wise product `*`?

Comment: do [`gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html#torch.gather) and [`scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) help here?

Comment: Yeah v[..] and w[..] are 1D vectors, so v[..] @ w[..] is a scalar